# Second to last Week of a Month

Tags: apscheduler

I have jobs that need to be scheduled on the second to last Monday of a month. Is this possible with current functionality?

From what I've seen, it doesn't seem to be possible with standard cron expressions.

Currently I have the job running every week and a check inside the job to see if it is the correct week, but I'd rather not use this set up as it still registers the job as running and being successful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer my question. I made a small addition to the cron expressions file in the apscheduler module and added a class that allowed for [-1, -2, etc]. Then was able to use that as an index for a calendar from the calendar module to grab the week I wanted. So now it allows for expressions like '-2 thu'.

If someone wants more help with how I implemented this, let me know.